# music/sound fx controller for options menu in BGE

Tags: audio

So I've been trying to find a way to control volume of the background music inside a BGE game I'm working on. But there's always some kind of hiccup.

I used the 3dsound and camera which kind of gets the job done for the options menu scene.

Then created a "game" scene which overlays the option menu scene so sound plays on that scene too.

But here's where the problem lies, the options menu ALWAYS has to be active on the game scene in order to play the sound.

Was wondering if there was a better way to do this either with python or logic bricks or if I'm not seeing something

[image]